# Error when adding new dependency to Gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle

My `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:weathericonview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.3'
}
```

Adding this dependency `'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'` to the gradle file redlines this part `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` from my gradle file and gives this following error:

```
All com.android.support libraries must the exact same specification. Found versions 24.2.1, 23.4.0
```

What does this mean? How do I avoid this conflict when adding that dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the new appintro dependency adds a sub-dependency on the support library, v24.2.1, but you already have an earlier one.

Update your direct dependency to the same version, which in practice will probably be fine, or you'll need to use an older version of appintro that in turn uses an earlier version of the support library.

That is, in the case of the former, change your line to:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1
```

Edit: I say 'probably fine', because the Android support library is a very stable set of APIs and continues to perform consistently across versions. Outside of that, often when a version change is required, you need to assess whether there are any breaking changes or altered behaviours.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change targetSDK from 23 to 24 too, but thats no problems for me.